# Swift `join` hangs when joining string with country flag

Tags: swift, emoji

I discovered this while working in Swift 1.2. I have reported it as a bug. But wonder why?

```
import UIKit

var str = " LHR ✈️ SFO "

([str] as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("") // Will work
join("", [str]) // Hangs forever
```

Comment: Interesting observation! The same happens with Xcode 7 beta 6 and Swift 2.

Comment: I can't get it to run in Swift 2: Cannot invoke join with argument list of type '(String, [String])'

Comment: Yep, I've just experience this too. Peculiar... and annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has this fix problem in swift 2.0, `join` is replace by another method `joinWithSeparator(separator: String) -> String` which works fine with flags.

Here is code snippet.

```
var str = " LHR ✈️ SFO "

([str] as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("") // Will work

[str].joinWithSeparator("")
```

Output

```
 LHR ✈️ SFO 
 LHR ✈️ SFO 
 LHR ✈️ SFO
```

Comment: Glad they did that, was very hard to trace.